# Compatibility mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-word-2010

When I downloaded 2007 files into 2010, Compatibility Mode in 2010 changed the format.

How can I convert back to the old format?

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2010 under `File / Info / Versions` check if anything is listed. If so, you can try reverting to a previous version of the document:

[image: 1]

If the document's formatting has been changed and saved and no previous versions are listed, I think you're out of luck unless you have a backup somewhere.